# Error while creating a slope

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, slope

I have a elevation raster (1 arc second) downloaded from USGS site. Before adding it to ArcMap I changed the display units to meters.The projection system for this raster is GCS_1983. When I use the slope tool under the spatial analyst tool , it is unable to create the slope layer.The data type for the image is floatng.What could be possibly be wrong here.

[image]

Even after reprojecting it I get the same error.
[image]

Comment: The cell size is 9.25925925930002e-005

Comment: You need to do more than change the display units.  You need to reproject the raster to a projection that uses metres and rerun the slope analysis.

Comment: The title says "Error" but no error seems to be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Despite changing the display units, your raster still is still using a Geographic Coordinate System.  Trying to run a slope analysis on such data is invalid.  Slope (rise/run) doesn't make sense with degrees as the unit because the distance of 1 degree at the equator is greater than 1 degree near the poles.

You will need to [reproject](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007q000000) your raster to a coordinate system that uses metres as the units.

Re-run your slope analysis on the new data and you should be fine.

Comment: How could I find which UTM zone for the raster to be reprojected.

Comment: Even after reprojection it doesnt help it...

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What projection did you use?

Comment: NAD 1983 UTM Zone 14N.The error is same as above in the original question here. Display units are in meters. Anything else I am missing here.

Comment: Your error message looks like it was cut off.  I can't see an error code.  FYI, changing display units will have no effect.

Comment: I have added the error while I am trying to create the slope layer again. Hope this helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8527/discussion-between-senthil-and-fezter)